# deleted value of the after delete trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I've got problems with my triggers (add and delete):

```
ALTER TRIGGER [trgAfterShoppingInserted]
ON [ShopingList] AFTER INSERT 
AS BEGIN
   DECLARE @cardId char(6), @points int, @userId int

   SET @cardId = (SELECT cardId FROM inserted)
   SET @points = (SELECT points FROM inserted)
   SET @userId = (SELECT userId from [Card] WHERE id = @cardId)
   IF @userId = 0
   BEGIN
   Update [Card]
   set points = points + @points
   where id =@cardId
   END
   ELSE
   Update [Card]
   set points = points + @points
   where id =@cardId OR
   userId = @userId
END


ALTER TRIGGER [trgAfterShoppingDeleted]
ON [ShopingList] AFTER DELETE 
AS BEGIN
   DECLARE @cardId char(6), @points int, @userId int

   SET @cardId = (SELECT cardId FROM inserted)
   SET @points = (SELECT points FROM inserted)
   SET @userId = (SELECT userId from [Card] WHERE id = @cardId)
   IF @userId = 0
   BEGIN
   Update [Card]
   set points = points - @points
   where id =@cardId
   END
   ELSE
   Update [Card]
   set points = points - @points
   where id =@cardId OR
   userId = @userId
END
```

The problem is on the `SET @cardId..`

The error is:

> *Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.*

how is it possibile ?

thanks for any help

Comment: Trigger is fired once per delete. You are deleting several records at once.

Comment: `deleted` contains multiple rows. If you can show us more of the trigger, we may be able to help re-write it to deal with this. Also, you should review any other triggers you've written - `inserted` can also contain multiple rows.

Comment: thank You now I understand, I edited post so that the code of triger is visible, is there ay way to make it work as I would like it to (for each row)?

Comment: Both triggers will not work if your insert or delete statement should ever insert or delete multiple rows. You need to stop assuming that your trigger only deals with a single row - that's just not the case. You need to rewrite your triggers to handle multiple rows at once (in the `Inserted` and `Deleted` tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both triggers will not work if your insert or delete statement should ever insert or delete multiple rows. You need to stop assuming that your trigger only deals with a single row - that's just not the case. You need to rewrite your triggers to handle multiple rows at once (in the `Inserted` and `Deleted` tables)

As an example - you could rewrite your `trgAfterShoppingDeleted` something like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [trgAfterShoppingDeleted]
ON [ShopingList] AFTER DELETE 
AS BEGIN
   UPDATE [Card]
   SET points = points - i.points
   FROM Inserted i
   WHERE Card.id = i.id AND i.UserId = 0

   UPDATE [Card]
   SET points = points - @points
   FROM Inserted i
   WHERE i.UserId <> 0 AND (Card.id = i.id OR Card.userId = i.userId)
END
```

You need to **think in sets of data** - don't assume single rows in your trigger pseudo tables, and don't do RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) processing in a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

`deleted` table contains the records that were deleted as part of a given `DELETE` statement and can contain multiple rows if the `DELETE` criteria matched multiple records.

This is what happened in your case and when you tried to select `cardId` from the `deleted` table that contained multiple records, the select statement is returning multiple values and so the trigger is throwing that exception.